# Use mysql with promises in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, node-mysql

I just followed the [tutorial for authentication on node from scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local).
They used mongodb as a backend, and I ported this to mysql. This is my first node app connecting to a database.

I used bluebird to `promisify` the `mysqljs/mysql` package in `config/database.js`

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(mysql);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);
```

Here is the code of my `model/user.js`:

```
const mysqlPool = require('../../config/database'),
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
    Promise = require("bluebird");
    getDb = function(){
        return mysqlPool.getConnectionAsync();
    }
let user = {
    create(user, done) {
        getDb().then((db) => {
            return db.queryAsync(`insert into bot_users (name, token, type, external_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`,
                [user.name, user.token, user.type, user.external_id])
        }).then((results, fields) => {
            console.log(results, fields)
            user.id = results.insertId
            return done(null, user)
        })
    },
```

There is something that does not look good to me:

```
getDb().then((db) => {
    return db.queryAsync(...)
}).then(...)
```

looks somehow convoluted. I would like to have a variable `db` that I could use directly as `db.queryAsync(...).then(...)`, but I'm not able to find out how to assign such a promise to the variable `db`.

Also I would like an advice on my approach. Is this a good approach to use promises here or is there a better one ?

Is it necessary to `return done(null, user)` inside the `then` callback in order to stick to the general node convention, or is this no longer required when using promises (bluebird) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important advice for any work with promises is: Ditch callbacks.

Your code currently is a hybrid between callbacks (`done()`) and promises. Don't do that. Use promises exclusively. The key point of promises is that you can *return* something from your async functions. You don't need to rely on the calling side passing in a callback.

Promisify all APIs. Emphasize on returning things.

```
const Promise = require("bluebird"),
    mysqlPool = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../../config/database')),
    bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt-nodejs'));

let user = {
    create: params => mysqlPool
        .getConnectionAsync()
        .then(db => db.queryAsync(
            'insert into bot_users (name, token, type, external_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
            [params.name, params.token, params.type, params.external_id]
        ))
        .then((results, fields) => ({
            name: params.name,
            token: params.token,
            type: params.type,
            external_id: params.external_id,
            id: results.insertId
        }))
};
```

Note how `user.create()` returns an unbroken chain of values. A mySQL connection turns into a query result turns into a new user object. I dislike overriding the existing instance. Avoid side-effects.

Usage is straight-forward.

```
user.create({
    name: "foo",
    token: 12345,
    type: "user",
    external_id: 67890
}).then(newUser => {
    console.log(newUser);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gives much insight. I was not aware of implicit return in arraw functions, and how it simplifies promises. You show me how to simplify to the max.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple return a promise from `create` method of the `user` model.

```
create(user) {
    return getDb().then((db) => {
        return db.queryAsync(`insert into bot_users (name, token, type, external_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`,
            [user.name, user.token, user.type, user.external_id])
    }).then((results, fields) => {
        console.log(results, fields)
        user.id = results.insertId
        return user;
    })
},
```

This promise will then resolve with the value of the user. So anywhere else you can use the method as

```
User.create(user)
.then(createdUser => { // do something with user here })
```

If you have access to latest versions of node (anything above 8), you can use `async-await`, to make the code even more simpler to understand.

```
async create(user) {
    const db = await getDb();
    const results = await db.queryAsync(`insert into bot_users (name, token, type, external_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`,
            [user.name, user.token, user.type, user.external_id]);
    user.id = results.insertId;
    return user;
},
```

An `async` function can be called like any other function, but it will return a promise which will resolve with the value returned. So the usage of the method still remains the same.

```
User.create(user)
.then(createdUser => { // do something with user here })
```

Comment: I'd like to accept both as answers. What is really interesting here is `async await`.

Comment: Yeah they make life as a JS developer a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are now at least two npm libraries to provide Node access to MySQL with Promises:

- [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/tree/master/documentation) has its own "[promise wrapper](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md)"
- [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) - "...a wrapper for mysqljs/mysql that wraps function calls with Bluebird promises"
- [mysql2-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2-promise) - "...small promises wrapper for mysql2, it's forked and compatible with mysql-promise"